# Ionic iOS promise never resolves

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise, ionic3, zonejs

I am implementing Google Sign-in in my Ionic 3 app with Firbase. I've successfully been able to use the [native Google Plus Cordova plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus), then login with credentials to Firebase using [Angular Fire 2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). Here is my code:

```
public loginWithGoogle(): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let loginPromise: Promise<any>;

      if (this.isMobile()) {
        loginPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.googleplus.login({
            'webClientId': '--------.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'offline': true
          })
            .then(res => {
              this.afAUth.auth.signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
                .then(firebaseRes => {
                  resolve(firebaseRes);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  reject(err);
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              reject(err);
            });
        });
      } else {
        loginPromise = this.afAUth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()) as Promise<any>;
      }

      loginPromise
        .then(res => {
          console.log('login promise done: ' + JSON.stringify(res));

          const user: User = {
            uid: res.user.uid,
            email: res.user.email,
            displayName: res.user.displayName
          };

          resolve(user);
        });
    });
}
```

And the call to it in my login page:

```
this.auth.loginWithGoogle()
  .then(res => {
    console.log('success login !!!!!');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error login !!!!!');
  });
```

However, when I deploy to iOS with Xcode, I can see the console output:

```
2017-06-11 11:32:01.384130 MyApp[2634:842028] login promise done: {"uid":"...","displayName":"...","photoURL":"..."...}
```

The promise never resolves ! I have tried using ZoneJS manually but unsuccessfully:

```
private zone;

public loginWithGoogle(): Promise<any> {

  this.zone = new NgZone({});

  ...

      this.zone.run(() => {
          resolve(user);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

But the result is the same. For information, login works fine in the browser.

Comment: My bad! Didn't pay enough attention. I removed my answer. My suggestion would be to  divide the `loginWithGoogle()` into two functions, one handling login on mobile and the other handles browser login (Separation of concerne). Then make the platform-check before calling either of the two. This will make the code easier to debug and, more readable, both for you and for others reading your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I rewrote my code with observables only, it's much more readable now. And I also found the problem ! Firebase signing with credentials does not return the same object interface than sign in with popup... The problem was that I was accessing res.user, which exists when signing in with popup, but does not exist when signing in with credentials. For the latter, properties `uid`, `email` and `displayName` are directly at the root of the object: `res.uid`, `res.email`... I find this quite misleading from a developer point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from accessing `res.user`, which only exists when signing-in with popup. The object returned when signing-in with credentials contains `uid`, `email` and other user properties at its root. You need to create the user differently whether you are on mobile or bower environments. On mobile, access `res.user.uid` and on browser access `res.uid`.

IMHO this is a misleading interface specification on Angular Fire's side.

Also, the code is hard to read. Promises chains are not a good practice. When possible, use Observables directly, and when not possible, convert promises to Observables using RxJS [fromPromise](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md) operator. You can then flatMap results to chain async calls and get a clean code. One advantage of Observables is that the error callback of the `subscribe` function will catch any error that occurred during the chain, while with promises you need to catch and reject manually.

With a bit of refactoring, you get the following (which works):

```
private signInWithGooglePlus(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(
    ...
  );
}

private signInFirebaseWithCredentials(idToken: string): Observable<User> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(
    ...
  ).map(credentials => ({
    uid: credentials.uid,
    ...
  }));
}

private signInWithGooglePopup(): Observable<User> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(
    ...
  ).map(firebaseRes => ({
    uid: firebaseRes.user.uid,
    ...
  }));
}

public loginWithGoogle(): Observable<any> {

  let loginPromise: Observable<User>;

  if (this.isMobile()) {
    loginPromise = this.signInWithGooglePlus().flatMap(res => this.signInFirebaseWithCredentials(res.idToken));
  } else {
    loginPromise = this.signInWithGooglePopup();
  }

  let user: User;

  return loginPromise
    .flatMap(userTmp => {
      user = userTmp;
      return this.getJWTToken(userTmp.uid);
    })
    .map(token => {
      this.storeData(token, user);
      return user;
    });
}
```